# How can I exclude -1 from this do…while loop?

Tags: c, do-while

The program is supposed to calculate the average of numbers entered until -1, but my code calculates the average with -1 included.

How can I exclude -1 from being calculated to the sum and average?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int n;
  int sum = 0, i = 0;
  float av;
  do {
    scanf("%d", &n);
    sum += n;
    i++;
  } while (n != -1);
  av = (float)sum / i;
  printf("%f", av);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your solution, your code would read the `n` which is equal to `-1` and add, and then verify which was causing this problem.

You could do it like this:

```
do {
  scanf("%d", &n);
  if (n != -1) sum += n;
  i++;
} while (n != -1);
```

Or even better, like this:

```
while (1) {
  scanf("%d", &n);
  if (n == -1) break;
  sum += n;
  i++;
}
```